# parsing html information with beautifulsoup4 in python

Tags: python, html, parsing

I am working on a python project with a friend, and we wanted to make something that will download the page http://projecteuler.net/problem and get the problem you select, then print it back like this:

Project Euler Problem 7: 100001st prime
    By listing the first six prime numbers: 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, and 13, we can see that the 6th prime is 13.

```
What is the 10 001st prime number?
```

for example, you would do something like python script_name.py 7 and it would print out ^^.

been trying to find multiple ways to do that, but I do not understand how beautifulsoup4 works. it would also be helpful to explain how the script works if you have it

thank you!

Comment: This is not a good question for SO, apart from being broad you have zero code in your question which equates to zero effort, the docs for BeautifulSoup are fantastic  so there is no excuse for not making some attempt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you to get started :

```
import sys
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

problem_url  = "https://projecteuler.net/problem={}".format(sys.argv[1])
problem_page = urllib2.urlopen(problem_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(problem_page.read())

problem_text = soup.find("div", {"class": "problem_content"}).text
print problem_text
```

Usage:

```
$ ./euler.py 4
```

Output:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>   Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.